# positioning section and div

Tags: html, css

I have a problem building a simple website.

I want to use  as my container for news (70% of wrapper's width), and  as my aside with most popular news, which should be positioned to the right of .

My  has display block and float left, while  has display inline.

It is ok, but the aside content doesn't behave as expected. If I put a  into it, it has wrapper's width, not aside's.

What can I do? When I try to add padding to my aside's list, I can't.

[jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmae2hL3/)

```
#aside {
    padding-left: 2em;
    width: 29%;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add your (*minimal*, *relevant*, **[mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)**) code into your question (otherwise when the pastebins die, or move, or simply fail, your question becomes useless to others in future). Also, for front-end web-development (HTML, CSS and JavaScript), it's often a very good idea, and is much-requested, to post a live demo to reproduce your problem at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar).

Comment: What exactly is your requirement here? The links above Footer should be displayed at right side under the Most Important Articles?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi no, when i add padding to #aside, h1 and list inside aside isnt padded and there is no green background below it. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmae2hL3/)

Comment: @BartoszSobczyński: Something like [this](http://prntscr.com/4hn243)?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi no, i'd like to have all aside green, not just lines. and 1, 2, 3, 4...10 should be all one below eachother

Comment: On the grounds that you're clearly participating, but have chosen to disregard my request to post your relevant, minimal code *in your question*, I'm voting to close as 'off-topic' as this is a "why isn't this working?" question, and lacks code to demonstrate the problem. Should you choose to address this, please [edit] your question to include both the (minimal) code and a link to the JS Fiddle you've created (though you need to strip that down to only the minimal code necessary to reproduce your problem).

Comment: @BartoszSobczyński: I have posted the answer with jsFiddle Demo.

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi thanks thats working! can i award u in this site any way? any rep points, pluses, best answer or smth?

Comment: Yes mark as answer which is given below by me and press up arrow to mark answer as useful. It will give points to me as reward.

Comment: @Syed Ali Taqi i need 15 reputation to upvote but i marked green 'v' :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use two `div` elements to divide your page to 70% and 30%. I have edited a bit of your **CSS** and it works:

**CSS:**

```
.sec
{
width:70%;
float:left;
background-color: red;  
margin-bottom: 3em;
}
.side
{
width:30%;
float:left;
background-color:Green;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
//your rest of HTML

<div class="sec">
                            <h1>Last news</h1>
                            <article>
                                    <h1>News #1</h1>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id velit deleniti ducimus, dolor architecto animi blanditiis laudantium quia fuga obcaecati, quibusdam maxime temporibus nihil porro, magnam doloribus explicabo, provident nesciunt! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla placeat odit eaque porro sint laudantium ad ipsam quisquam numquam error dolor, laboriosam saepe aperiam, rerum libero ullam fugit quidem, ab.</p>
                            </article>
                            <footer>
                                    <ul>
                                            <li>Author: admin</li>
                                            <li>date: 31.12.2003</li>
                                    </ul>
                            </footer> <!-- date and author #1 -->
                            <!-- news1 -->

                            <article>
                                    <h1>News #2</h1>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id velit deleniti ducimus, dolor architecto animi blanditiis laudantium quia fuga obcaecati, quibusdam maxime temporibus nihil porro, magnam doloribus explicabo, provident nesciunt! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla placeat odit eaque porro sint laudantium ad ipsam quisquam numquam error dolor, laboriosam saepe aperiam, rerum libero ullam fugit quidem, ab.</p>
                            </article>
                            <footer>
                                    <ul>
                                            <li>Author: admin</li>
                                            <li>date: 31.12.2003</li>
                                    </ul>
                            </footer>  <!-- date and author #2 -->
                            <!-- news2 -->

                            <article>
                                    <h1>News #3</h1>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id velit deleniti ducimus, dolor architecto animi blanditiis laudantium quia fuga obcaecati, quibusdam maxime temporibus nihil porro, magnam doloribus explicabo, provident nesciunt! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla placeat odit eaque porro sint laudantium ad ipsam quisquam numquam error dolor, laboriosam saepe aperiam, rerum libero ullam fugit quidem, ab.</p>
                            </article>
                            <footer>
                                    <ul>
                                            <li>Author: admin</li>
                                            <li>date: 31.12.2003</li>
                                    </ul>
                            </footer>  <!-- date and author #3 -->
                            <!-- news3 -->

                    </div>
                    <div class="side">
                            <h2>Most popular articles</h2>
                            <ul>
                                    <li>Example article #1</li>
                                    <li>Example article #2</li>
                                    <li>Example article #3</li>
                                    <li>Example article #4</li>
                                    <li>Example article #5</li>
                                    <li>Example article #6</li>
                                    <li>Example article #7</li>
                                    <li>Example article #8</li>
                                    <li>Example article #9</li>
                                    <li>Example article #10</li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
//your footer code here...
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rq14fu6v/)